# How to change the text highlight color?

Tags: vbscript

The weight of the day yesterday, I tried to add this code so that it changes the highlight color of the text to the one shown in the picture. I found a lot of information on the Internet, but unfortunately, it does not work in the context of my code.
What to do?) How to change the color of the text selection?

```
Option Explicit
Dim WA,WD,Sel  ' Объявляем переменные
'Создаем объект¬–приложение Microsoft Word
Set WA=WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application")
' Можно было использовать конструкцию
' Set WA=CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WD=WA.Documents.Add  'Создаем новый документ (объект Document)
WA.Visible=true  ' Делаем Word видимым
Set Sel=WA.Selection  'Создаем объект Selection
Sel.Font.Size=14 'Устанавливаем размер шрифта
Sel.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=1  'Выравнивание по центру
Sel.Font.Bold=true  'Устанавливаем полужирный шрифт
Sel.TypeText "Понятие сценариев" & vbCrLf  'Печатаем строку текста
Sel.Font.Bold=false  'Отменяем полужирный шрифт
Sel.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=0  'Выравнивание по левому краю
'Печатаем строку текста
Sel.TypeText " Сценарий – это пакетный файл, позволяющий автоматизировать действия системного администратора."
```

[The end result (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eobm.png)

Comment: Relevant [Changing highlighted text to a different color](//stackoverflow.com/q/229865) but will need the Named Constants defining before use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HighlightColorIndex` property with one of the **WdColorIndex** constants: 
[WdColorIndex enumeration (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex)

With the code you provided, you would use `Sel.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 10` I think, but you can experiment.

You can also use `Sel.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor` with the same constants or an RGB value directly.

Comment: Would recommend when working with COM Libraries to always replicate the "Named Constants" in your code instead of using magic numbers. i.e. `Const wdTeal = 10`.